# Best practice upgrading bootnodes

Tags: bootnode

What is the best practice for upgrading boot nodes on a live chain ( if we don't have the node id file ) ?
Just change the node id in the genesis file, recompile and upgrade all the bins ?

Comment: Why would you want to recompile if you're only changing the bootnode address? Just make the relevant changes in the generated chain spec file and you should be good to go. Also on preexisting nodes that are syncing you can pass the new peer id address with the `--bootnodes` flag.

Comment: because we need to distribute it on the complete network ( more than 300 nodes ) and not on a dev one.

Comment: It depends then on what method are your users running. Are they running the node with a flag such as `--mainnet`, if so then yes what you say is the right way, but then users would have to download more data as compared to simply downloading a chainspec. on the other hand if you are just distributing the chainspec, there's no need for any of that.